# how to check exception AND EXCEPTION MESSAGE in phpUnit 6?

Tags: phpunit

In PhpUnit 5 we was able to set expected class name and then to check it's error message

```
$this->setExpectedException('Cake\Network\Exception\NotFoundException');
$this->assertEquals('Not Found', $this->_exception->getMessage());
```

How to do the same in PhpUnit 6?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

```
$this->expectException(NotFoundException::class);
$this->expectExceptionMessage('Not Found');
```